# View (fabIcon) background can not be changed inside its onClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-drawable, floating-action-button

I have the following fab Icon but when i click it, the button's background doesn't change into save Icon.

```
  fabEditAttendance = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_attendance_edit);

            fabEditAttendance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                   fabEditAttendance.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save);

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you try using view rather than fabEditAttendance?? I know sounds dumb just give a try though :) view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save);

Comment: ok wait i will give it  atry

Comment: Any luck??? Laxman

Comment: yeah bro , i tried another method and it worked form me , setImageResource worked for me

Comment: Good :) I noticed that it is FloatingActionButton just now :) Anyway glad you solved it :) Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks  :)  you indirectly are also responsible for the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : i had to use

```
 setImageResource(int resID);
```

not

```
setbackgroundResource(int resID);
```

Solution Looks like this :

```
fabEditAttendance.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save);
```